# MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST SuiteScript even after i have added ".js"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am having some issue for the SuiteScript while trying to create a new one. I followed other answers to add ".js" at the end of the script file name, but the error still showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFDCG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFDCG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHymU.png)

Is there any other ways to solve the problem?

This is the error:

Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/TF_LIB_MassDeletionScript2.0.js","stack":[]}

Comment: Can you share the code? If not possible, just share the header line where you define modules. define([],function(){}); Problem lies there

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the error is telling you that a module referenced in the script file you are trying to upload cannot be found. Don't forget that the system parses your script file when you try to upload it, so if there are syntax errors or other problems, the file cannot be uploaded.  Make sure that the TF_LIB_MassDeletionScript2.0.js file is in the SuiteScripts folder before you try to upload your YY_Script.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, you need to exclude the file extension in the TF_LIB_MassDeletionScript2.0 module relative reference. (just the reference, not the module file name)

Also, a "." in a relative reference tells the compiler to go back a level, so you probably need to rename your module file to something like TF_LIB_MassDeletionScript2_0 and update the reference